# How to reorder the x axis on a stacked area plot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, stacked-area-chart

I have the following data frame and want to plot a stacked area plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(11)
df <- data.frame(a = rlnorm(30), b = as.factor(1:10), c = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 10))

ggplot(df, aes(x = as.numeric(b), y = a, fill = c)) + 
    geom_area(position = 'stack') +
    theme_grey() +
    scale_x_discrete(labels = levels(as.factor(df$b))) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

The resulting plot on my system looks like this:

[image: stacked_area_plot]

Unfortunately, the x-axis doesn't seem to show up. I want to plot the values of `df$b` rotated so that they don't overlap, and ultimately I would like to sort them in a specific way (haven't gotten that far yet, but I will take any suggestions).

Also, according to `?factor()` using `as.numeric()` with a factor is not the best way to do it. When I call `ggplot` but leave out the `as.numeric()` for `aes(x=...` the plot comes up empty.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Trying this seems to work: `scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, max(as.numeric(df$b))), breaks = seq(0, max(as.numeric(df$b)), 1))`

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave `b` as a factor. You will further need to add a `group` aesthetic which is the same as the `fill` aesthetic. (This tells `ggplot` how to "connect the dots" between separate factor levels.)

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = b, y = a, fill = c, group = c)) + 
    geom_area(position = 'stack') +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

As for the order, the x-axis will go in the order of the factor levels. To change the order of the axis simply change the order of the factor levels. `reorder()` works well if you are basing it on a numeric column (or a function of a numeric column). For arbitrary orders, just specify the order of the levels directly in a `factor` call, something like: `df$b = factor(df$b, levels = c("1", "5", "2", ...)` For more examples of this, see the r-faq [Order bars in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5208679/903061). Yours isn't a barplot but the principle is identical.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot! I was missing the `group=c` part.